# How can I avoid Groovy's XmlNodePrinter converting encoded newlines &#xA; into an actual newline

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using XmlParser to read in an XML document that has some content like this:

```
<instructions size='1'>
   <instruction key='manifest'>
      Bundle-SymbolicName: org.slf4j.api&#xA;Bundle-Version: 1.6.4.v20120130-2120
   </instruction>
</instruction>
```

Notice on the 3rd line there is entity for newline, `&#xA;`

The problem is when I use Groovy's XmlNodePrinter to print out this document (in my case I've made changes elsewhere to the document), the node printer will print out the text node and use a real newline instead of `%#xA;`

```
<instructions size='1'>
   <instruction key='manifest'>
      Bundle-SymbolicName: org.slf4j.api
Bundle-Version: 1.6.4.v20120130-2120
   </instruction>
</instruction>
```

I have set the trimWhitespace=false for the XmlParser object and also set preserveWhitespace=true for XmlNodePrinter however this doesn't change the aforementioned behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text inside `<![CDATA...]]>`:

```
<instructions size='1'>

   <instruction key='manifest'> 
   <![CDATA[       
       Bundle-SymbolicName: org.slf4j.api&amp;#xA;Bundle-Version: 1.6.4.v20120130-2120 
   ]]>
   </instruction>
</instructions>
```

I'm testing it using the following the code:

```
def out = new StringWriter() 
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(new File("file.xml").text) 
def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)) 
printer.print(xml) 
println out.toString()
```

The output is as expected:

```
<instructions size="1">
   <instruction key="manifest">
      Bundle-SymbolicName: org.slf4j.api&amp;#xA;Bundle-Version: 1.6.4.v20120130-2120
   </instruction>
</instructions>
```

**RESPOND TO COMMENT:**

If you really have no choice, than you can extends `XmlNodePrinter` (this is a Java class) and create Groovy code such as:

```
class MyXmlNodePrinter extends XmlNodePrinter {
   MyXmlNodePrinter(PrintWriter out) {
      super(out)
   }

   void printSimpleItem(Object value) {
      value = value.replaceAll("\n", "&#xA;")
      out.print(value)
   }
}

def out = new StringWriter() 
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(new File("file.xml").text) 
def printer = new MyXmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(out)) 
printer.print(xml) 
println out.toString()
```

The output of this code is:

```
<instructions size="1">
   <instruction key="manifest">
      Bundle-SymbolicName: org.slf4j.api&#xA;Bundle-Version: 1.6.4.v20120130-2120
   </instruction>
</instructions>
```

That `MyXmlNodePrinter` is trivial and doesn't perform escaping, so you may need to copy (and change) `private void printEscaped(String s, boolean isAttributeValue)` from `XmlNodePrinter`.  You can find the source code of `XmlNodePrinter` in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/util/XmlNodePrinter.java

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Unfortunately I don't control the creation of the first file, and I want to make as few changes to it as possible.

Comment: I've changed my answer to respond your comment :)